# Ruby / Rails gems and plugins that need some rails3 love?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, open-source, rubygems

I'm just getting started with rails and ruby and i wanna start giving back to the community,

Are there any cool gems / plugins that spring to mind that need some tlc or rails 3 fixes that i could start contributing on?

I know your sposed to scratch your own itch.. but most the gems i use work great! :-P

Thanks..

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Contributing to Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_rails.html) and take a look at [Github](http://www.github.com/), a lot of gems (including rails) are hosted there, it has a cool issue tracking system so you can fork and start patching :)

Answer (score 0):

- [Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic). It needs to be refactored to use ActiveModel. Also take a look at the feature request at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues).

Comment: Authlogic has already been upgraded to be Rails 3 compatible by someone but his changes weren't merged into the official repository. I don't think the library is being maintained anymore.

Comment: Yes that is why it needs some love.